# Ajax / jQuery - append new items but check don't already exist in DOM

Tags: ajax, jquery, dom

I have a container div which includes lots of element divs all of which  have a unique ID.  I then make an ajax call to get more elements and append these to the DOM.

This works using the function below but I need to check that what I append doesn't already exist in the DOM. I've been looking into using  each() and possibly remove() or detach() in order to do this, but I am not sure of jQuery syntax and really need some assistance.

```
function loadMoreItems(url) {
    $.get(url, null, function(data) {
       var container = $(data).find('#container');
       var newItemsHTML = "";  

       /*-- not sure what to do in between
       container.find('.element').remove();
       container.each('.element').detach();
        --*/

        newItemsHTML = $(container).html();
        var $newItems = $(newItemsHTML);

        $container.isotope('insert', $newItems, true);

    }, 'html');
}


<div class="element" id="id_172977"></div>
```

Comment: `find("selector").remove()` will work. Did you tried it first?

Comment: how do I know what selector to remove?  I need to know whats in the DOM first before I can remove from the new items

Comment: Then I don't get your question. You can traverse DOM easily, we don't know what selector to remove as well. If you need to select it programmatically, you should reveal algorithm.

Comment: Think I got it. You need to remove from your fresh `data` divs with id's which already appended to body?

Comment: I basically don't want repeated elements displayed on the page. Ideally I somehow to need to check what ID's are already in the DOM to ensure I don't select any new elements from the ajax call that are the same ID.  Or if thats not possible, then simply replace existing elements so that they're not repeated

Comment: Assuming all of appended divs has class `element` you can do `$(".element").each(function() { container.find("#" + this.id).remove(); });`

Comment: Thats sounds like what i need but it isn't working.  I have still have two items the same displaying.

Comment: Logic itself is working. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chjr8/ You should debug it further, I don't think I can help more than this.

Comment: thank you, I will see if I can get that working in my code.  If you put this as the answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of appended divs has class `element` you can do

```
$(".element").each(function() { 
   container.find("#" + this.id).remove(); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chjr8/)

Comment: thanks you for your help with this.  I was getting an error due to having an empty ID on an element but it now works.  Many thanks!